# Why do original paypal IPN (sandbox) requests not get sent to my listener

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've created an IPN listener and have tested it out with the simulator. It works just fine. With one of my sandbox accounts I place an order through my app (using the MPL for this). My IPN listener logs nothing. I login to my sandbox account and look at the ipn history. The IPN has failed, but there is no response code. After 8 retries I am then able to do a manual resubmit. When I do this my listener receives the request just fine.

Why would the original requests fail, but the resubmit works just fine?

Comment: Check your web server logs to get a look at the result that your server is sending back to PayPal.  You should be able to see actual error messages here, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have immediate access to the logs... so I put a listener on my own server and it looks like the original request is getting there. Thanks! I'll open a ticket with my hosting company.